# MBP 15" Late 2011 Lion audio noise

Tags: macos, audio

Today I noticed something unusual on my MBP's audio.

When I played some music on youtube today, I noticed that something was different. The sound is noisy, like when in a car, you put the volume very high, it starts distorting. But, on low volume on my Mac, it creates the same effect.

Anyone with the same problem? Anyone knows how to fix it? It didn't do it earlier... Maybe some SO update messed up the audio drivers/codecs?

> **Update:**
>   I performed a [PRAM and NVRAM reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1379) and a [SMC reset](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964) and it didn't solve anything.
>
> Also, deleted the *.plist files in `~/Library/Preferences/Audio` as suggested [here](https://discussions.apple.com/message/15705402#15705402) and again, it didn't solve anything.
>
> I'm getting desperate...
>
> ---
>
> **Update2:**
>   Got in recovery mode, started `Disk Utility` and used the options `Fix disk` and `Fix disk permissions` and once again, it didn't solve anything.

Comment: Anyone? It's really anoying...

Comment: Does it only do it with that one video or with every video or song? Does it happen in iTunes or when using QuickTime? Also, which OS version are you running 10.7.4? Do you have any software that has changed your volume/music settings?

Comment: Your question is a little vague, so it's a bit hard to determine what might have been the cause. When did you first notice the issue? Did anything significantly change that may have caused the audio distortion? Any recent installs? Have you recently made any changes to /Utilities/Audio MIDI Setup?

Comment: I'm running 10.7.4, installed all the recent updates. It happens in every song, even with system sounds. @harpermd I checked the Audio MIDI Setup and I think it's all ok... de_an777 I don't think that I have any software that has changed my volume settings... Request me more info so that you try to determine what might have been the cause for this, I don't really know what info can help to do it...

Comment: I really need help on it, please anyone!

Comment: When you are on lower volume, does the noise get quieter too, or is it pretty much the same? I'm wondering if it is the software putting out distorted sound, or broken hardware. Do you use a lot of bass boost and/or play sound at high volume frequently?

Comment: It gets quieter too. Probably is software problem, got to try to boot ubuntu live cd and test the sound to see if it's the same thing...

Comment: just curious- is the startup chime distorted also?

Comment: Nope, the startup chime isn't distorted, so I think that is software related... Also, I can't boot Ubuntu live CD on my MBP :(

Comment: @silentw how are you trying to boot the Ubuntu live CD? are you holding down the 'c' key after the boot chime? if so, how did you burn it?

Comment: one more question- if you plug in headphones into the MacBook, does the distorted noise come through the headphones as well?

Comment: yes, it does...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all sound from your machine is distorted there may be a hardware problem with your Mac's speakers.

To test, I would reinstall Lion from your recovery partition and see if it is the same. If you still have problems with the sound you should take your Mac to an Apple Authorised Service Provider.

Comment: From my guess (since startup chime isn't distorted (as suggested test by iphonedev46)), it is software related, not hardware. Reinstall Lion would be my last resource, maybe any way to reset audio settings?

Comment: @silentw you have already reset audio prefs with nvram reset. In my experience with niggly problems like this it is usually quickest to reinstall the OS (aka 'archive and install'). This preserves all of your data, apps and user preferences if you're worried about that. It also wipes any non default, possibly conflicting kexts or preferences very efficiently.

Comment: I guess I'll try that, but since I'm finishing a project, I guess I'll delay that action, thanks!

Comment: Just updated to Mountain Lion and I still have this sound problem. Do you think that if I follow your method it will do anything? Thanks!

Comment: @silentw in all honesty, no probably not, you've basically done what I've described by upgrading to 10.8. I would get a second opinion on the sound at an Apple store (or similar) if possible next.

Comment: Freshly reinstalled (Clean Disk then Reinstall) Mac OS X Mountain Lion from Recovery HD and the noise is now gone, whooooaaa!